# Number Reversal in c++

Tags: c++

When I pass an odd digit number > 1 to the function, I am getting 1 less than the actual result I should be getting and the code is working perfectly fine for an even digit number, I am not able to figure out why.

```
int rev_number(int num){
int arr [10];
int i=0;
int j=0;
int rev_num=0;
while(num > 0){
    arr[i] = num%10;
    num = num/10;
    i++;
}
i--;
while(i>=0){
    rev_num += arr[j] * pow(10,i);
        j++;
        i--;
    }
    return rev_num;
}
```

Comment: Why on the earth you're complicating the simple logic ?

Comment: Works for me. Can you give an example number where this fails?

Comment: any 3 digit number, take 457 for instance,  you should get 754. but instead you will get 753.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid using `pow` which return a `double` while you only want to manipulate integers. For example, imagine if the result of `arr[j] * pow(10,i)` is 753.99..., the cast would only put 753 in `rev_num`! In some cases, that will work, but not always. It's a fifty-fifty chance to work.

Try replacing:

```
rev_num += arr[j] * pow(10,i);
```

to

```
rev_num = rev_num * 10 + arr[j];
```

Have you tried to round or to add .5? Does that also fix your problem?

Comment: If `pow` returns a double for integers, it should give an erroneous answer in case of 4 digit numbers too, but when you pass 1234 to the function, you correctly get 4321 as the answer.

Comment: I don't understand why it should give an erroneous answer in that case. The problem is that if you obtain 4.000000001 and 3.99999999 because of a precision error due to double, when you cast to int, you obtain either 4 or 3. That's a very "random" behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

How about the following simple code

```
int reverseNumber(int num) {
     int reverse = 0;
     while(num > 0) {
          reverse = reverse*10 + num%10;
          num = num/10;
     }
return reverse;
}
```

Comment: Forget my last comment. I need some rest :). +1 for your answer, it's indeed a way better solution. However I would not use "reverse" for both the variable name and the function name, that can generate errors with some other languages.

Answer (score 1):

Since `pow` deals with floating point values, it's integer representation may get truncated, so certain values may end up being lower than expected.

A better solution is to use integer math, such as this:

```
while(i>=0){
rev_num *= 10;
rev_num += arr[j];
    j++;
    i--;
}
```

There are several other ways to express the same thing, and storing the values in an array isn't strictly necessary, you could just multiply the modulo value back in.

However, my favourite "reverse a number" is to read it in as a string, and then use the standard reverse function.

So, something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::string s;
   std::cin >> s;
   std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
   std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

All code examples of the function showed here are invalid because the function does not process valid integer 0. So I decided to show a correct function realization.:)

```
using System;

namespace ReverseNumberExercise
{
    class Program
    {
        static int ReverseNumber(int x)
        {
            int y = 0;

            do
            {
                long digit;
                x = ( int )Math.DivRem( x, 10L, out digit );
                y = y * 10 + ( int )digit;
            } while ( x != 0 );

            return (y);
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter an integral number: ");

                string input = Console.ReadLine();

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) break;

                int x;

                if (!int.TryParse(input, out x))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid number. Try again.");
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Reversed number is: {0}", ReverseNumber(x));

                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nGood bye!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is about C++, not C#. And you said the other functions are invalid. I don't think Akshat's code is invalid.

Comment: @Maxime, I did not want to show C++ code because it is an assignment. As for validaty of code then all code except mine is invalid. As the parameter defined as int then it can be for example equal to zero (zero is valid number) or even negative. In this cases functions of others do not output anything. So my solution is the best.

Comment: I disagree for the 0 case.

Comment: Why? 0 can be passed as argument. 0 is the same integer number as others. What is for example the difference between 0 and 1?! And what about negative numbers? If you want to exclude negative numbers then it would be correct to define the parameter as unsigned. So all other functions are simply stupid. One more my code is the best provided that you understand something. I wrote the code in C# because it will be useful for the author of the thread to try to rewrite the code in C++ on his own.

Comment: Calm down. Take the code provided by Akshat. Pass 0 in input. This function returns 0. This is correct.

Comment: Yes, it returns 0, But this condition    while(num > 0) can only confuse readers. The best loop in my opinion is do { /*..*/{while ( num!= 0 ); That is any number always has a digit. So at first we extract this digit and then check whether there are other digits. This logic is more clear.

Comment: Anyway, your answer states: [the other solutions] "are invalid because the function does not process valid integer 0" which is wrong.

Comment: Because as I said the condition while(num > 0) only confuses readers and from logical point of view is invalid. It is not in accordance with the type of the parameter. Declaring the type as int you are saying in fact that the domain consists from negative and positive numbers but inside the function there is condition while(num > 0). In my opinion it is an example how code should not be written.